# Distinct Dates between records that overlap days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an instance where I need to calculate the number of distinct days between records where the dates overlap. Below is an example:

```
                  Start Date         End Date
Record 1          5/1/2017           6/15/2017
Record 2          5/15/2017          6/30/2017
```

Basically, I need to count from 5/1/ - 6/30, but only need to count 5/15 - 6/15 once. And I could have more than two records. Tried using a calendar table, but couldn't get the code right.

Comment: do you have a calendar table in the database?

Comment: @SGibbs-  You need the count of records which are overlapping ?

Comment: I need to count the distinct dates if the records are overlapping. I am using T-SQL

Comment: I think you need to get `MIN(Start Date)` and `MAX(End Date)`, then to run Common Table Expressions (CTE) or `While` loop

Comment: @SGibbs, we want to know what specific database are you using.

Answer (score 0):

Using a calendar table:

```
select count(distinct c.date)
from calendartable c
join tablename t on c.date between t.startdate and t.enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL, but not using a calendar table...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,start_date DATE NOT NULL
,end_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2017-05-01','2017-06-15'),
(2,'2017-05-15','2017-06-30');

SELECT DATEDIFF(LEAST(x.end_date,y.end_date),GREATEST(x.start_date,y.start_date)) diff 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.end_date > x.start_date 
   AND y.start_date < x.end_date 
   AND y.id < x.id;
+------+
| diff |
+------+
|   31 |
+------+
```

or something like that.